# Is there a better way to collect tax?

Tags: new-little-kings-story

I only just realized that i could send a recruit into a house to collect tax, however i don't have all that many houses and i'm already doing a lot of work to go to each one and sent someone in.

I am wondering if there is a better way to collect tax without having to visit every house and aim a recruit at the door?